# Adding GridView items from the left in beginning of grid (android)

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview

I would like to create an app with a gallery similar to Instagram, in which adding a photo to the gallery creates a thumbnail which appears in the beginning of the GridView, rather than the end.

Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bUploadImage"
            android:text="Upload Image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/gridview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:columnWidth="90dp"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:rotationY="180"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageAdapter

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Image> items;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Image> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.mContext = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 500));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap((items.get(position)).getBitmap());
        return imageView;
    }

    public void notifyDatasetChanged(ArrayList<Image> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private ImageAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<Image> items = new ArrayList<Image>();

    Button bUploadImage;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bUploadImage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);
        bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        adapter = new ImageAdapter(this,0,items);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.bUploadImage:
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
                break;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                Image i = new Image();
                i.setBitmap(bitmap);
                items.add(i);
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(items);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that your `notifyDatasetChanged` actuly doesn't notify anything. It just changes reference to array but `ArrayAdapter`s inner list is unchanged. You just need to call `adapter.add(bitmap)` and it will trigger `notifyDatasetChanged` himself. All work is already done inside `ArrayAdapter` implementation.

To solve your problem change your adapter to look like so:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Bitmap> {
    public ImageAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Bitmap> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                android.R.drawable.btn_plus);
        //set btn_plus as first element  in array
        insert(bm, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(480, 500));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(getItem(position));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Also to track click event on `GridView` items you need to subscribe to `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` :

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
       if (position == 0) {
           Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
           startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
           return;
       }

       //Handle click on image
    }
});
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. Implemented alongside the answerer above and it worked great.

Comment: @y_arl If I've answered your question please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the location where it should go

```
list.add(0, yourObject);
```

Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right.